# Closest Ancestor function that works with data rather than node pointers

Tags: c, algorithm, tree

I am writing a program to find the closest ancestor in a binary tree (not BST). I found a sample working code:

```
mynode *closestAncestor(mynode* root, mynode* p, mynode* q)
{
   mynode *l, *r, *tmp;

   if(root == NULL)
   {
      return(NULL);
   }

 if(root->left==p || root->right==p || root->left==q || root->right==q)

   {
     return(root);
   }
   else
   {
      l = closestAncestor(root->left, p, q);
      r = closestAncestor(root->right, p, q);

      if(l!=NULL && r!=NULL)
      {
        return(root);
      }
      else
      {
         tmp = (l!=NULL) ? l : r;
         return(tmp);
      }
   }
}
```

I am trying to do something like the following (passing only the data values and finding only the data value of ancestor, not concerned with its pointer)

```
int closestanc(node * root, int n1, int n2)
{
    int l, r;
    if(root == NULL)
        return -1;
    if(root->right->data == n1 || root->right->data == n2 || root->left->data == n1 ||     root->left->data == n2)
        return root->data;
    else
    {
        l = closestanc(root->left, n1, n2);
        r = closestanc(root->right, n1, n2);
        if(l!= -1 && r!= -1)
            return root->data;
        else
            return (l != -1 ? l : r);
    }
}
```

Comment: i might not have read the question properly but what is the issue? Just clarify it either in the title or in the question..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check for `NULL`s. Change:

```
if(root->right->data == n1 || root->right->data == n2 ||
   root->left->data  == n1 || root->left->data  == n2)
```

to

```
if ((root->right != NULL && (root->right->data == n1 || root->right->data == n2))
 || (root->left  != NULL && (root->left->data  == n1 || root->left->data  == n2)))
```

Though I suspect you can replace it with a simpler:

```
if (root->data == n1 || root->data == n2)
```

without changing what the function will output (although it will change how it works a bit).

**Additional note:**

The function is not exactly too reliable. It seems that if both don't exist in the tree, it will still return an ancestor. For this I suggest returning `-2` (or another unused value) instead of `root->data;` for the above check so you can identify when both aren't found.

So:

```
if (root->data == n1 || root->data == n2)
    return -2;
```

Then:

- If the function returns `-1`, you know neither of the elements were found.
- If it returns `-2`, it only found one of them.
- If it returns anything else, that's the closest ancestor.